# Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I have created a custom `Entry` class below:

```
class GameEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, state='normal', font='helvetica', bg='white',
                 fg='black', bd=7, selectborderwidth=7, relief="ridge", relx=0, rely=0,
                 relwidth=0.175):
        super().__init__(master=master, state=state, font=font, bg=bg, fg=fg,
                         bd=bd, selectborderwidth=selectborderwidth, relief=relief)
        self.place(relx=relx, rely=rely, relwidth=relwidth)
```

And a custom `Button` class below:

```
class GameButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, state='normal', text=str(), font="helvetica",
                 bg="black", fg="white", bd=5, relief="ridge", activebackground="gray",
                 activeforeground="black", command=None, relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.1):
        super().__init__(master=master, state=state, text=text, font=font, bg=bg,
                         fg=fg, bd=bd, relief=relief, activebackground=activebackground,
                         activeforeground=activeforeground, command=command)
        self.place(relx=relx, rely=rely, relwidth=relwidth)
```

I also have a `raize()` function for the button

```
def raize(var):
    print('var ', type(var))
    print(var.get())
    return var.get()
```

This is how I am using the `GameEntry` class and `GameButton` class:

```
self.entry_0_1 = GameEntry(self.background, relx=0.175, rely=0.185)
self.set_inputs_button = GameButton(self.background, text='button', command=lambda:
                                    raize(self.entry_0_1), relx=0.175, rely=0.4)
```

[image: Here's what the output looks like]

My problem is that I want to set default characters in the `GameEntry` widget and the user of the app will either change those characters or keep them, and then when the `GameButton` is clicked the `raize()` function will either return the default characters or the new characters the user inputted. Those characters will then be used for some calculations. I am using `.insert()` which displays the characters I insert but when I try to `.get()`, I am running into `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

```
self.entry_0_1 = GameEntry(self.background, relx=0.175, rely=0.185).insert(0, '0.0')
self.set_inputs_button = GameButton(self.background, text='button', command=lambda:
                                    raize(self.entry_0_1), relx=0.175, rely=0.4)
```

The code above returns the following in the console after I click the button

```
var  <class 'NoneType'>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\py\gui.py", line 134, in <lambda>
    self.set_inputs_button = GameButton(self.background, text='button', command=lambda: raize(self.entry_0_1), relx=0.175, rely=0.4)
  File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\py\gui.py", line 52, in raize
    print(var.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

With the following code

```
self.entry_0_1 = GameEntry(self.background, relx=0.175, rely=0.185)
self.set_inputs_button = GameButton(self.background, text='button', command=lambda:
                                    raize(self.entry_0_1), relx=0.175, rely=0.4)
```

I get this in the console

```
var  <class 'gui.App.__init__.<locals>.GameEntry'>
1.0
```

In summary I want to be able to set a default value in an `Entry` and then click a button to either get that default value in the `Entry` or a new value that the user can input.

Comment: `GameEntry(...).insert(...)` is no longer giving you an Entry of any sort, it's giving you the result of `.insert()` - which is None.  You need to do that part as a separate statement from the creation of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

**Setting default value**

You can set the default after initializing like this:

```
# set default value
self.entry_0_1.insert(0, '0.0')
```

Note: the call to `self.entry_0_1.insert(0, '0.0')` can be placed anywhere after the variable is defined. However, it is generally considered good practice to initialize your variables (e.g. GUI elements) first, then perform any operations.

Note 2: you could also modify your constructor for the `GameEntry` class so that you can pass in a default value from the start:

```
class GameEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, 
                 ...
                 relwidth=0.175, default_val="0.0"):
        super().__init__(...)
        self.place(relx=relx, rely=rely, relwidth=relwidth)
        self.insert(0, default_val)
```

**Bonus - getting notified about input without the button**

As [@jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) pointed out, the `.get()` method works fine to get the current input. However, let's say you want to do some kind of validation on the input text - as the user is typing, rather than waiting for them to click the button.

To do this, you can use the `textvariable` option when you initialize an instance of `GameEntry`. It needs to be an instance of the Tkinter class `StringVar`:

```
class GameEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, state='normal', font='helvetica', bg='white', 
                 fg='black', bd=7, selectborderwidth=7, relief="ridge", relx=0, rely=0, 
                 relwidth=0.175, default_val="0.0"):
        # Define text variable to pass into the init for Entry below
        text_var = StringVar(container=self)
        super().__init__(master=master, state=state, font=font, bg=bg, fg=fg, 
                  bd=bd, selectborderwidth=selectborderwidth, relief=relief,
                  textvariable=self.text_var)
        self.place(relx=relx, rely=rely, relwidth=relwidth)
        self.insert(0, default_val)
```

Comment: `.get()` works just fine on the Entry itself; the only situation in which you actually need a StringVar associated with the Entry is if you're going to put a write trace on the Var (to be immediately informed if the user edits the value).

Comment: For doing validation, the built-in validation features of the `Entry` widget are arguably better than using a variable trace.